# Problema al crear dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy trabajando con un componente `tabs` dentro de un `tab` estoy tratando de colocar un `dataTable` pero me marca un error y no se cual el es el problema. Aquí dejo código que estoy utilizando.

Código Script

```
<script>
var id_maestro = <?php echo $maestro->id_usuario; ?>;
var tabla_grupos;

$(document).ready(function(){   
    declararDataTable();
});

function declararDataTable()
{
    var id_ciclo = $("#id_cicloVal").val(); 

    tabla_grupos = $('#grupos').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ grupos por página",
                "sZeroRecords": "No existen grupos",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ grupos",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 grupos",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Encontrados de _MAX_ grupos)"
        },
        "aoColumns": [{"sWidth":"10%"},{"sWidth":"15%"},{"sWidth":"20%"},{"sWidth":"20%"}],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../includes/acciones/get_grupos_json.php',
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "id_maestro", "value": id_maestro });
            aoData.push({ "name": "id_ciclo", "value": id_ciclo });
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 25
    });
}
</script>
```

Este es el código html

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#grupos" data-toggle="tab">Grupos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#timeline" data-toggle="tab">Timeline</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="active tab-pane" id="grupos">
      <form class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label style="margin-right: 4px;">Ciclo Escolar</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="id_cicloVal" onChange="obtenerGrupos();">
        <?php
          $ciclos = Ciclo::getLista();

          if(is_array($ciclos))
          {
            foreach($ciclos as $ciclo)
            {
        ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $ciclo["id_ciclo_escolar"]; ?>">
               <?php echo $ciclo["nombre"]; ?>
             </option>
        <?php
            }
          }
        ?>
        </select>
       </div>
      </form>
      <table id="grupos" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Clave</th>
         <th>Grado</th>
         <th>Materia</th>
         <th>Carrera</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
     <!-- /.tab-pane -->
     <div class="tab-pane" id="datos">
     </div>
     <!-- /.tab-pane -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.tab-content -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.nav-tabs-custom -->
```

Este es el error

[image: Imágen de error]

Comment: Y cual es el error que le muestra?

Comment: ya encontre el error, tienes un div con el mismo id que el de la tabla en el active tab-panel

Comment: Tenias razón @SebastiánLagosYañez, tenia un div con el mismo id que el que le había puesto en la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

En el HTML tienes:

```
 <div class="active tab-pane" id="grupos">
```

y luego más abajo tienes:

```
<table id="grupos" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
```

Entonces en ambos nombras el id identicos, o sea, id ="grupos".

Te explico:
Cuando ocurre, este error normalmente se debe a un error del selector (id) en el selector jQuery que se usó para inicializar el DataTable. Si intenta inicializar DataTables en cualquier otro tipo de elemento, en lugar de fallar silenciosamente, recibirá un error de DataTables que indica el mensaje que tienes.

Suerte!

Comment: Hola. Donde has puesto "datos" imagino que haz querido decir "grupos"

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroC. Tienes razón. Lo repararé