# Crear un datatable a partir de un json con claves y valores

Tags: javascript, json, datatable

Estoy tratando de crear un datatable en HTML usando JS, el mismo tiene que tener como source mi .json, el problema es que antes utilizaba un json de prueba de un tutorial que estaba usando que es el similar al siguiente

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
```

pero mi nuevo json es el siguiente

```
[
    {
        "A/M": "100/50",
        "Clase": "Mago",
        "Faccion": "Criminal",
        "Nivel": "21 (74.61%)",
        "Nombre": "Test1",
        "Raza": "Gnomo"
    },
    {
        "A/M": "20/0",
        "Clase": "Mago",
        "Faccion": "Criminal",
        "Nivel": "1 (0)",
        "Nombre": "Test2",
        "Raza": "Humano"
    },
    {
        "A/M": "0/2",
        "Clase": "Clerigo",
        "Faccion": "Ciudadano",
        "Nivel": "50 (0)",
        "Nombre": "Test3",
        "Raza": "Elfo Drow"
    },
    {
        "A/M": "0/0",
        "Clase": "Paladin",
        "Faccion": "Criminal",
        "Nivel": "21 (0)",
        "Nombre": "Test4",
        "Raza": "Humano"
    },
    {
        "A/M": "0/0",
        "Clase": "Clerigo",
        "Faccion": "Ciudadano",
        "Nivel": "1 (0)",
        "Nombre": "Test5",
        "Raza": "Elfo"
    }
]
```

ya no tiene el "Data":

¿Como puedo hacer para cargarlo en esta función?

El error que estoy recibiendo es 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "language": {
  "search": "Busqueda: ",
  "loadingRecords": "Cargando..."},
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    ajax: 'test.json'
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al crear dataTable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163578/problema-al-crear-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que por defecto el `DataTable` espera que el `JSON` tenga el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "data": [
    // row 1 data source,
    // row 2 data source,
    // etc
  ]
}
```

<kbd>[Fuente](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#Types)</kbd>

---

#### Solución:

Si queres conservar el formato de tu `JSON`, solo tenes que establecer [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) igual a vacío.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "test.json",
    "dataSrc": ""
  }
});
```

Comment: Estoy recibiendo un error, pero creo que es porque estoy definiendo mal la tabla.

¿Tengo que escribir el nombre de encabezado cuando creo la tabla o se crea automáticamente del archivo?

              <table id="example" class="table" style="">
                  </table>

y en el .js tengo que definir las columnas o se crean solas?

Comment: No estoy entendiendo lo del encabezado. Si te referís al `thead`, no, no hace falta. Respecto a las columnas, si, en JS al datatable, usando la propiedad `columns`, tenes que indicarle en que propiedad de cada objeto están los datos. [Acá un ejemplo](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: Estuve intentado durante esta hora y no puedo lograr que me muestre los datos.
```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "ranking.json",
        "dataSrc": ""
        "columns": [
            { "Nombre": "Nombre" },
            { "Clase": "Clase" },
            { "Raza": "Raza" },
            { "Nivel": "Nivel" },
            { "Faccion": "Faccion" },
            { "A/M": "A/M" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```
¿esto es correcto o tengo que entrar de otra forma?